# SharedPreferences with listview

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

i have a real problem and i don't know how to solve it , 
i try to use sharedpreferences on my application to save some item on listview . 
cause when i don't have internet i have exeption on my apllication so i try to save informations to have it when i don"t have connexion , i used sharedpreferences but i didn't know how to use it in the main or on my adapter  cause i have many textview . here my asynchtask from main :

```
class FetchRecentPosts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {         
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", getString(R.string.loading_message));
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            articles = Services.getRecentPosts();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            for (Article article : articles) {
                System.out.println(article.getTitle());
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            ArticlesAdapter adapter = new ArticlesAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, articles);
            articlesList.setAdapter(adapter);



        }
```

and this is my adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = convertView;
        Article article = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.imageviews.imgArticle);

            TextView txtArticleTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.textviews.txtArticleTitle);
            TextView txtArticleExcerpt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.textviews.txtArticleExcerpt);
            TextView txtArticleDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textArticleDate);

            txtArticleTitle.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshape(article.getTitle()));
            txtArticleExcerpt.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshape(article.getExcerpt()));
            txtArticleDate.setText(article.getDate().toGMTString());

            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(view.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
            txtArticleTitle.setTypeface(tf);

            imageLoader.displayImage(article.getImg(), image, options);
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to save in the SharedPreferences? What is the Exception you are getting? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: i return informations from json . and everything is good when i have internet , but when there is no internet the application stopt , i want that information to be saved , that when i start my application the last information shows up , mean to have an offline application .

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand you would like to save the downloaded data returned from json into your application. And when you launch it offline, you want them to be appeared from shaeredPreferences.

This is how I would do:

First, if I do not have connection I dont want to have that exception either so I would examine if the app has internet connection:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The data might be saved into sharedPreferences Array. You can learn more about it at http://www.b2creativedesigns.com//sharedpreferences.php . You might want to clear the arrays everytime you launch the application online and after this you can save those data you need into these arrays. Then it is obvious that you have to read the information from the sharedPreferences arrays into the listview.

Comment: thank you  jani , i will try with this even that's make me crazy :D thank you .

Comment: and i have a questions should i use sharedpreferenses on my adapter or mainActivity ? i'm confused ?

Comment: You should use it in your MainActivity

Comment: Since you wish to create an offline application you only have 2 chances: sharedPreferences and sqlite database, but the database is far more complex than this. Not to mention that as I see you will only use 3 arrays (title, exercpt, date) plus the ones related to the image loader which is still managable I think.

Comment: yes that what i will try to do , i need just the title ,date and exerpt to save , thank you i'm trying right now to solve this problem thank you again

Comment: i try with it and don't know it's not working att all :( don't know why :( even  " isOnline " dosen't work too :(

Comment: i am using the methods above and they work well. Try to log the isOnline first, then check the arrays, they should be fine

Comment: nothing happened :( sharedpreferences dosen't work :( have the same things as before

Answer (score 0):

FYI if your application contains huge amount of data it is recommended that use SQLITE instead of ShatedPreferences and if u want to work your application in offline also you can do one thing

this will help you to check the active data connection

```
 public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

case 1) if your having data connection get the records from the webservice call and iterate it and insert each record into database and write a common adapter , make sure it will work with both online and offline data and show it in list or what ever you want

case 2) if you don't have active data connection fetch the records from the database and prepare adapter and show it in list or what ever you want